# How to trigger Elastic Beanstalk redeployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the easiest way to trigger an Elastic Beanstalk redeployment from within AWS?

The goal is to just reboot all instances, but in an orderly manner, according to ALB / target group rules.

Currently I am doing this locally via the EB shell by calling `eb deploy` without doing any code changes. But rather than doing this manually on a regular basis, I want to use CloudWatch jobs to trigger it with a schedule.

Comment: Redeployment of the existing application, or deployment of a new version?

Comment: Redeployment of the existing version. I just need the instances to reboot in an orderly manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to setup CloudWatch [Schedule Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) rule.

The rule would trigger a lambda based on your per-defined schedule. The lambda can be as simple as to only **trigger the re-deployment** of the existing application:

```
import json
import boto3

eb = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = eb.update_environment(
        ApplicationName='<your-eb-app-name>',
        EnvironmentName='<your-eb-env-name>',
        VersionLabel='<existing-label-of-application-version-to-redeply')
        
    print(response)
```

You could customize the lambda to be more useful, e.g. by parametrizing it instead of hard-codding all the names required for `update_environment`.

The **lambda execution role** also needs to be adjusted to allow the actions on EB.

The other option would be to use **CodePipline** with two stages:

- Source S3 where you specify the zip with the application version to deploy. Its bucket must be versioned.
- Deploy stage with Elastic Beanstaslk provider.

The pipeline would also be triggered by the CloudWatch rule on a schedule.

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, `VersionLabel` would have to be specified as the latest version. Is there a placeholder like `$LatestVersion` so I don't have to specify the version explicitly?

Comment: @Manuel Not sure. the label is what you want it to be. So I guess you could always deploy under same label. Though this would have to be tested to know for sure if its possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I unaccepted it because I found an even easier way, see my own answer. I have not heard of that feature before, maybe it was not even available when you wrote this answer.

Comment: @Manuel Ok. But your solution terminates instances and starts new ones, which is much slower than redeploying an application version. And this is what you asked for, not about how to terminate instances and start new ones.

Comment: That's a good point. I reaccepted your answer because it more specifically answers my question, rather than rewriting my question. The time difference is minuscule in my case, but you are right that rebooting / redeploying instances is not the same as replacing them, just thinking about lost burst credits, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a feature called [Instance Refresh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-instance-refresh.html?icmpid=docs_ec2as_help_panel) that replaces the instances without deploying a new app version.

Triggering that via a Lambda function scheduled via CloudWatch Jobs seems to be the easiest and cleanest way for my use case. However, keep in mind that replacing instances is not the same are rebooting / redeploying, for example when it comes to managing burst credits.

This AWS [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-refresh-for-ec2-auto-scaling/) described how to set up a scheduled instance refresh with AWS Lambda.